# Peculiar issue with regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to print all the file names in the current directory which do not have a trailing "~" character to it.
The files in the directory are:

```
mnt.txt
xyz.pl
abc.pl
abc.pl~
```

The output should be

```
mnt.txt
xyz.pl
abc.pl
```

I am using the following logic -

```
@arr= qx( ls -A );
$pattern = "[a-z|A-Z|0-9]*\.[a-z]*[^~]";
foreach $fname (@arr){
if ( $fname =~ m/${pattern}/g )
{
print $fname;
}
```

But it is not working, it all the filenames.

However  if I change `$pattern` to `"[a-z|A-Z|0-9]*\.pl[^~]"` then its output is correct.

What can I do to fix this? Please guide as I want all files including text to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Birei 's answer is correct, but to answer your question, you have to anchor your regex:

```
$pattern = qr"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+[^~]$";
```

Comment: There is no need to parse the entire file name `qr/[^~]$/` will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid parsing the output of `ls`. Alternatively you can use `opendir()` and `readdir()` functions to read directory content and `grep()` to filter them, like:

```
perl -e '
    opendir $dh, q|.|; 
    for ( grep { ! m/~$/ } readdir $dh ) { 
        printf "%s\n", $_ 
    }
'
```

Comment: But i am getting the  o/p for the pattern "[a-z|A-Z|0-9]*\.pl[^~]". why does it match one and not the other ?

Comment: @Samboy786: A pipe in a character class does not have the meaning you think it has. Last `[^~]` makes the regex to match at least one character. The `\.pl` doesn't match `txt` files. Your regex neither uses anchors to begin and end of a string. It fails in many ways.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the answer from @M42. I noticed that i didn't use \$ towards the end and that was creating problems.